# Azure Cosmos / DocumentDB issue when setting custom id property

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I want to insert documents to documentDb. This is working fine when I'm not adding a custom id property before inserting the doc.

Example

```
foreach (dynamic doc in docs)
{
    if (doc != null)
    {

        doc.id = Convert.ToString(doc.myCustomId); // myCustomId is an integer
        var addedDoc = await dbClient.UpsertDocumentAsync(collectionUri, doc);
        addedDocuments.Add(addedDoc);
    }
}
```

When I remove doc.id => the document is added with a guid as id.

The error is the following: "Can not convert Array to String."

```
"   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.op_Explicit(JToken value)\r\n   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject(Type objectType)\r\n   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject[T]()\r\n   bei Microsoft.Azure.Documents.JsonSerializable.GetValue[T](String propertyName)\r\n   bei Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Resource.get_Id()\r\n   bei Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.ValidateResource(Resource resource)\r\n
```

The code is executed in a Azure Function

Comment: What version of Newtonsoft.Json and the DocumentDb nuget package are you using? I think this may be an issue related to version mismatches.

Comment: What is the value of doc.myCustomId?

Comment: @brettsam newtonsoft version is 10.0.3 and I have checked all deps in the project and every nuget packages references the same version 10.0.3

Comment: @JesseCarter it an integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error can occur if you use a version of `Newtonsoft.Json` higher than 9.0.1. Try moving everything back to that version and see if it works. I'd also recommend using the `DocumentDB` package 1.13.2 to be safe.

This happens because the host is compiled against a specific version of these packages and if you try to use a newer version you can get subtle breaks like this. See this issue for details on how we're looking to address this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/992.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This was the problem and it's really strange, because when serializing the dynamic object to a defined c# object and then adding it to document-db it's working.